# Do I need to do SEO if I cross 1 million visits a month?

Tags: seo, marketing

I was wondering if I need to do SEO to my site after it crosses 1 million visitors a month.

I don't see the point of it. People who are visiting the site can build links from me. But I read else where that SEO is continuous.

Or is it the type of website I have? Because I think that there is a difference between let's say a meme site with millions of pictures like memecenter.com or a blog that publishes 1 article every week.

The first one cannot build links to the millions of pictures while the blog must promote their articles. Am I right, can someone confirm my theory?

Comment: Not all sites get their traffic from SEO.   SEO doesn't work for every site.   Some sites can't get by without it.   It all depends on the site.

Answer (score 2):

SEO is a long term investment and it can be done at the beginning of the website launch or after you reach x number of traffic. It depends on the individual when they would like to do the SEO.

There is no wrong or the right time to start SEO.

Link building: The intention should be to build rich content which people would love and let people naturally link to your website.

Strategy: Generally people link to content which they love and intention should be to build rich experience regardless of the industry.